# Style only the image shown with data-media

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to create some responsive images with `data-media` which is working out quite nicely. Unfortunately when i try to style my thumbnails it literally shows all outlines of the thumbnails which i dont wish, as the class should only be applied to the shown image.

```
<p><span class="post-img" data-picture data-alt="An unsual picture" >
    <span class="img-thumbnail" data-src="/generated/2014-03-06-some-article/IMG_1394-13*10-f320b4.jpg"></span>
    <span class="img-thumbnail" data-src="/generated/2014-03-06-some-article/IMG_1394-134*100-f320b4.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 100px)"></span>
    <span class="img-thumbnail" data-src="/generated/2014-03-06-some-article/IMG_1394-201*150-f320b4.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 940px)"></span>
    <noscript>
      <img src="/generated/2014-03-06-some-article/IMG_1394-13*10-f320b4.jpg" alt="An unsual picture">
    </noscript>
  </span></p>
```

The example is shown here with a random image from google images: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bugmi

As seen on the result, there are clearly three outlined thumbnails acting as placeholders. The example does not seem to work as expected with codepen, but i think most would understand the concept.

Comment: and where is your css? The output window shows nothing

Comment: You'll probably need to do `.img-thumbnail img { /* your styles here */}`, as this script dynamically adds an `img` tag inside the span (which ever data-media query the page size falls in to.)

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan, the only active CSS is the one from bootstrap, which should be in the codepen header.

Comment: @NickR, can you please reformulate that answer, i don't think i understood entirely. Thanks!

Comment: @JavaCake You're using this Script right? https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill It automatically adds an img tag inside the span tag. So you need to style that img.

Comment: @NickR, well spotted. It all makes sense now! Is there a way to refer a class to another class? I want to use the bootstrap "img-thumbnail" if possible.

Comment: You might have to copy the css of `img-thumbnail`, and create a new class, like `span.img-thumbnail img {  /* add bootstrap css */}`

Comment: @NickR, i may go with that solution.